# View related tables in Visual Studio 2012 like in LINQPad

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, linqpad

I saw that LINQPad 4 can show me all [related tables](http://www.linqpad.net/images/mainscreenshot.png) (I can see it in a drop-down list of table fields). Names of related tables are references to the list of the fields of this table.
Is there any way to watch related tables in Visual Studio? (For example, inside Server Explorer or SQL Server Object Explorer)

Answer (score -1):

using Following code you can see all table name in Combox name as   cmbTableNames

```
            DataTable tables = new DataTable("tablenames");
            adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE (TABLE_TYPE = 'TABLE')", con);
            adpt.Fill(tables);
            cmbTableNames.DataSource = tables.DefaultView;
            cmbTableNames.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
```